# Is there a way to add a custom button to an angular material autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm currently using an autocomplete input component which works fine but lacks a certain functionality. The component gets all needed data by a query which is fired as soon as the page is loaded and selects a pre-defined default entry. However there are always at least >10 entries available, but in order to show them it is necessary for the user to clear the current itemselection of the autocomplete. Once the selected item is cleared the component shows all entries and filters them corresponding to the user's input. 
Is there a way to create a customized version of the autocomplete component where I can add a button to show all entries regardless of the currently selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem is not a lack of functionality but an issue regarding the use of floating label within this component. I found some pretty helpful information in this issue on git: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2727

There a workaround was given by a user named nobol which would solve my problem. By using a directive in order to clear the autocomplete field the problem can be solved:

HTML:

```
<md-autocomplete md-floating-label="LABEL"
             md-selected-item="$ctrl.model" md-search-text="$ctrl.searchText"
             md-selected-item-change="$ctrl.itemChanged($ctrl.model)"
             md-items="item in $ctrl.items" clear-autocomplete
             md-autoselect="true" required>
```

Directive:

```
angular
  .module('yourModule')
  .directive('clearAutocomplete', clearAutocomplete);
function clearAutocomplete($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      const button = angular.element('<md-button>').addClass('clear-autocomplete');
      button.append('<i class="material-icons">clear</i>');
      element.append(button);
      let searchTextModel = $parse(attrs.mdSearchText);
      scope.$watch(searchTextModel, function(searchText) {
        if (searchText && searchText !== '' && searchText !== null) {
          button.addClass('visible');
        } else {
          button.removeClass('visible');
        }
      });
      button.on('click', function() {
        searchTextModel.assign(scope, undefined);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This solved my problem, so thx to nobol on github!